# Saving a list of objects to text file

Tags: c#

Hello im trying to save a list of objects into a text file. Below is the code im using.

The problem im having is that instead of displaying a string for each item like:

"BMW|6 Series|2007|10900|17000|Convertible|Automatic|Petrol|".

It is displaying: "Car_Manager.Car" for each item in the list. Thanks for your help.

```
    private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save everything in a dialog box
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        // Open the file and save the information
        Stream textOut = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textOut);

     foreach(Car c in cars)
        {

            writer.WriteLine(c);
        }
            writer.Close();

    }
```

Comment: You can't just expect your `Car` to output as a string.  What should its display value be?  See HimBromBeere's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `ToString()` method or write a new method to  write out each property value separately.

e.g.

```
public string ToDelimitedString()
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.Append(String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", this.Make, this.Model, this.Year));
    return result.ToString();
}


foreach(Car c in cars)
{
    writer.WriteLine(c.ToDelimitedString());
}
```

By default objects are converted to strings via their `ToString` method, which returns the object type name as a default.

Out of interest, why are you writing them to a text file? Xml serialization is ideal for this sort of situation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer works well, I think I have to use it for the project I'm doing.

Answer (score 6):

You have to implement `ToString`-method:

```
class Car 
{
    public override string ToString() 
    {
        return this.Name;  // or whatever property you need for your car-models
    }
}
```

This provides a string-representation for every car in your list which is then used by `WriteLine()`.

Alternativly instead of using `WriteLine(c)` you may simply use `WriteLine(c.Name)`.

What you currently see ("Car_Manager.Car") is the default-implementation which is inherited by every class as it is implemented on the object-class. So you may simply override it whith the given statem,ents and you´re done.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use an extension method. Something similar to the below.

```
public static class CarExtensionMethods {
    public static string TextFileString(this Car car) {
        return string.format("{0}|{1}|{2}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year);
    }
}
```

Then use as follows

```
var carString = car.TextFileString();
```